# What is the difference between many body theory and quantum field theory methods in condensed matter?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, terminology, definition, many-body

I am starting to studying condensed matter theory and I do not understand if Many-Body Quantum Mechanics and Quantum Field Theory are just synonyms or are two different methods.

It seems to me that the first is used when the starting point is a many-body wavefunction and then the occupation numbers formalism is adopted. In the second case, the starting point is a classical field which is quantized to describe some features of a material.
However, in the end, it seems to me that the types of techniques are the same (Green's functions, Path integrals, Faymann diagrams and so on).

Are just two synonyms and QFT is just the cooler, newer name of the same topic or are they different methods?

Comment: Many-body theory and quantum field theory are just synonyms. They're both quantum mechanical theories of many particles. Any difference in connotation is just due to history.

Comment: Usually the term "many body theory" is used for non-relativistic theories of many particles, while the term "QFT" is mostly used for relativistic quantum theories. The main difference is that in many body theories the total number of particles is conserved (at least in closed systems), and thus the tools of second quantozation, fock spaces, etc. are a mathematical convenience that allows to do more efficient computations. On the other hand, in relativistic theories the number of particles is variable due to the possibility of particle creation and annihilation.

Comment: In this context the aforementioned tools are necessary to describe the theory in a proper way.

Comment: @knzhou but in QFT particle number is not conserved whereas in many-body theory (assuming we're both talking about the occupation number representation of non-relativistic many-body quantum mechanics) particle number is conserved. Am I wrong in this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They overlap at least, and they may even be synonymous, depending on who you ask. Specialists in different fields often end up borrowing each other's ideas and methods, and the lines between them often become blurred or found to be nonexistent in the first place. Refs 1, 2, 3, and 4 are just a few of the many examples. And by the way, the author of ref 1 is a [Physics SE user](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/9444/xiao-gang-wen).

To explain why the meanings of "many body theory" and "QFT methods" are so fluid, I'll give a broader perspective that includes relativistic QFT.

The broad class of models that includes models called "many body theory" and models called "QFT" can be characterized like this:$^\dagger$ instead of assigning observables to individual particles, observables are assigned to regions of space (in the Schrödinger picture) or spacetime (in the Heisenberg picture). In such models, individual particles don't carry their own observables, but we can have observables that *detect* particles in a given region of space(time). This approach is important even if the total number of particles is conserved, because particles (like fermions or bosons) are often *indistinguishable* — which is really just a cryptic way of saying that the model's observables are tied to space(time) instead of to individual particles.

$^\dagger$  <sup>In topological QFT (TQFT), "spacetime" is a misnomer because such models don't have a metric field, and observables may not be assigned to *local* (contractible) regions. TQFT is still a rich subject because we can consider the model on a whole class of different spacetimes simultaneously. This is also an interesting thing to do in non-topological QFT, but I won't go into that here.</sup>

Here are a few comments to highlight the diversity within this broad class of models:

- It includes both strictly nonrelativistic and strictly relativistic models, and also models that are neither strictly nonrelativistic nor strictly relativistic. One example of the "neither" type is a variant of quantum electrodynamics with strictly nonrelativistic electrons: the number of electrons is conserved, but the number of photons is not.
- It includes models where the total number of particles is conserved, and models where it is not conserved. (More generally, within a single model, the total number of a given species of particles may be conserved for some species and not for others.) This is different than the distinction between relativistic and nonrelativistic models. The total number of particles is conserved in relativistic models that don't have any interactions at all, and it's not conserved in many nonrelativistic models. Even in nonrelativistic models where the number of "fundamental" particles is conserved, we still often have emergent *quasiparticles* (like spinons and holons) whose number may not be conserved.
- It includes models that assign observables to regions of continuous space and also models that assign observables only to discrete lattice points. The latter is not limited to condensed matter, and it's not limited to numerical calculations. In fact, lattice QFT is currently the most broadly applicable method we have for constructing relativistic QFTs nonperturbatively. A strict continuum limit may not always exist (unless we forfeit the interactions that make the model interesting), but we can still take the lattice spacing to be much smaller than the Planck scale, and that's close-enough-to-continuous for all practical purposes.
- Many of the models that were originally conceived for condensed matter turn out to define relativistic QFTs when the parameters are tuned to make the correlation length much larger than the lattice spacing, and this situation has enriched both subfields. We can use techniques originally developed for relativistic QFT to study critical points and phase transitions in condensed matter, and we can use techniques originally developed for condensed matter to help construct new examples of relativistic QFTs — or sometimes just new and enlightening ways of constructing familiar examples.

Whatever we call them, interesting models whose observables are tied to space(time) are so diverse that any attempt to neatly classify them is doomed. The more we learn about the subject, the more apparent this becomes. Words like "many body theory" and "QFT methods" are little more than vague clues about some of the kinds of things the author/speaker *might* be referring to. We just can't rely on words like that to convey anything precise, unless the author/speaker tells us exactly how we should interpret them in that particular article/lecture.

---

**References:**

1. X.G. Wen (2004), *Quantum Field Theory of Many-Body Systems: From the Origin of Sound to an Origin of Light and Electrons*, Oxford
2. Zinn-Justin (1996), *Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena*, Oxford
3. Abrikosov, Gorkov, and Dzyaloshinski (1963), *Methods of Quantum Field Theory in Statistical physics*, Dover
4. McGreevy (2016), "Where do quantum field theories come from?" (https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/s14/239a-lectures.pdf)

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. In my mind, many body theory always meant the occupation number representation of non-relativistic many-body quantum mechanics". When I then heard people saying it's equivalent to QFT, I got confused. I guess my question to you is, with this less broad definition of many body theory, it is not equivalent to QFT, right?
(even though I do understand that the point of your answer is that it is a bit ill-defined for the many reasons you have outlined)

Comment: @TheQuantumMan Right. Here's an example from Fetter and Walecka's *Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems* (1971), in the start of ch 1: "In principle, the $N$-body wave function ... [has] all possible information, but a direct solution... is impractical. [We will] resort to other techniques, [such as]... quantum-field theory... In a relativistic theory, the concept of second quantization is essential to describe the creation and destruction of particles. Even in a nonrelativistic theory, however, second quantization greatly simplifies the discussion of many identical interacting particles."

Comment: @TheQuantumMan I don't know if Fetter and Walecka's book uses the exact words "many body theory" anywhere, but they do say "$N$-body" and "many particle," so I think that's an example of what you're talking about. So that's a case where "many body theory" refers to a subset of QFT, at least if we define QFT as "observables are tied to space" as their book seems to do, instead of being a synonym for QFT. And since QFT is often used in the narrower sense of *relativistic* QFT, some might even say that they don't overlap at all.

Comment: This clears up a lot of confusion. At the end of the day it boild down to definitions and what matters is knowing the tools that you want to use, but thank you for clearing up some of my confusion.

Comment: Really nice answer.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly coming back to this, as stated here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361856/why-is-quantum-mechanics-called-01-dimensional-qft
quantum mechanics is a 0+1-dimensional QFT. But what happens in many-body QM? If, in at least certain cases many-body QM is equivalent to 'some' QFT, how do you reconcile the two? This is not a criticism, just a curious question.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan Interesting question! Answering in words is difficult because words are so ambiguous. Answering in math is easy. The math-answer is hard to fit in a comment-box, but chat doesn't play nice with math, so I'll use comments.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan Start with the nonrelativistic QFT of a single species of spinless particle in $1+1$ dimensional spacetime. The field operator $\psi(x,t)$ annihilates a particle at location $x$ and time $t$, and its adjoint $\psi^\dagger(x,t)$ creates one. The vacuum (no-particle) state $|0\rangle$ satisfies $\psi(x,t)|0\rangle=0$. Observables at time $t$ are generated by operators of the form $\psi^\dagger(x,t)\psi(y,t)$. ...

Comment: @TheQuantumMan ... One-particle states are
$$
\int dx\ f(x)\psi^\dagger(x,t)|0\rangle,
$$
where $f(x)$ is a function. On such states, the operators 
$$
X(t)\equiv \int dx\ x\psi^\dagger(x,t)\psi(x,t)
$$
and 
$$
P(t)\equiv \int dx\ \psi^\dagger(x,t)(-i\nabla)\psi(x,t)
$$
act like the QM position and momentum operators. If we think of the theory in terms of the observables $X(t)$ and $P(t)$ acting on 1-particle states, then it's 1-particle QM with observables are parameterized only by time. We can call that a 0+1 dimensional QFT, because $x$ is no longer parameterizes observables. ..

Comment: @TheQuantumMan ... 2-particle states are $\int dx\ f(x,y)\psi^\dagger(x,t)\psi^\dagger(y,t)|0\rangle$ where $f(x,y)$ is a function. $P(t)$ still acts like the total-momentum operator, but now we don't have a position operator tied to individual particles, because $X(t)$ is the center-of-mass position operator for the whole system ("total position operator"). But we can still ignore the field operators and use observables like $P(t)$ and $X(t)$ instead. We call that many-body QM, even though it's really just the 2-particle sector of a $1+1$ dimensional QFT. ...

Comment: @TheQuantumMan ... I suppose we could *also* call it a 0+1 dimensional QFT because observables are no longer parametersized by $x$, but I don't see much value of that language. It's just a word game. Thinking of it as the 2-particle sector of a $1+1$ dimensional QFT is much more productive, because it clarifies what the "identitical particle" business is all about. We can also think of single-particle QM as the 1-particle sector of a $1+1$ dimensional QFT (which is also more productive, IMO).

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly The 1+1 you wrote refers to the spacetime dimensions here, or the "effective" spacetime dimensions in the field theory (like the 0+1 from above)? What confuses me is that although in the path integral formulation of single-particle QM, we integrate over time; but don't we do the same for $N$ number of particles?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly also, from what you say, I expect that many-body QM is the part of 1+1 dimensional QFT that contains all the N-particle sectors for all N. Is this correct or a vast generalization? It doesn't sit well with my naive intuition, saying that an N-particle QM is equivalent to a sector of a 1+1 dimensional QFT, for any number of dimensions. I probably got half of it wrong :D

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Given what you said, I think that many-body QM is not just QFT with fixed number of particles, as many people say. Indeed, if many-body QM covers all the N-particle sectors of a QFT, I see no reason why the particle number should be conserved if we allow "communication" (very loose language used here) between the sectors. And many thanks for the detailed comments by the way. I'm starting to think that it's better if I just ask this on a separate post.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan The $1+1$ refers to the spacetime dimensions. (I used 1d space so that I could write the spatial argument as $x$ instead of $\vec x$ or $\mathbf{x}$), but we could use $3+1$ instead without changing the message at all. Yes, $N$-body QM is the part of $D+1$ dimensional QFT that contains only the $N$-particle states for that one value of $N$, whereas the QFT contains all of the $N$-particle states for all $N$.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan **Here's the key:** The $N$-body QM formulation is a valid alternative only if the QFT does not have any observables that mix different values of $N$. Then the subspaces with different $N$ are **superselection sectors**. (That's what superselection sectors means: the theory has no observables that mixes them.) On the other hand, if the QFT does have such observables, then we cannot split the model into separate (for each $N$) $N$-particle QM models.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly So, indeed, QFT is more general. I wonder why many people equate the true in every case.