# Bosonization in 0+1 dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, bosonization

We know examples of [bosonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosonization) in 1+1 dimensional spacetimes, as well as some examples in 2+1 and 3+1 space-time dimensions are known in literature. Does this also work in quantum mechanical models in 0+1 dimension?

Comment: bosonization comes up a little differently in lattice systems vs QFTs. are you specifically asking about general versions of Jordan-Wigner or bosonization in QFT?

Comment: I mean generalization of QFT Bosonization in 0+1 dimension. In a recent paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11929 it was argued that this might actually be problematic to do it in 0+1 dimensional QFT.

Comment: What do you call 0+1 dimension ? Is it one-particle Hilbert space? I.e. Hilbert space is $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: @lcv I think the OP is simply referring to "usual" QM (in field theory lingo). See, for example, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361856/why-is-quantum-mechanics-called-01-dimensional-qft).

Comment: @keisuke.akira yes that is what I meant. Essentially the Hilbert space is $L^2(Q)$ where $Q$ is configuration space.